# Reading isolated multichannel input with voltage drop on all channels

Tags: pcb-design, voltage-divider, opto-isolator, parallel, digital-isolator

I am building a circuit to read atleast 22 input channels (24 vdc) using an Arduino board which essentially works on 3.3 vdc or 5 vdc.

My current setup makes use of 22 PC817 optocoupler. I am sharing the most basic circuit diagram below with only one channel reading capability to keep it simple to understand.

[image]

To drop the voltage and keep the optocoupler safe, I've used a voltage divider with a 68K and 1.5K Resistance (±5%/±10% tolerance) that would drop the voltage to around 3.3 vdc, that I think would be safe for PC817 (please correct if I'm wrong).

Now since there are 22 channels to read, using 22 x PC817, 22 x 68K and 22 x 1.5K resistance adds a lot of complexity to the circuit, I wanted to know if there's a better way to do it.

I read about 8 channels Digital Isolators like [Si838x](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si838x-DataSheet.pdf), and have following questions:

1. From what I understand I can feed 24 vdc directly to this IC and will be able to handle?
2. If not, is there any other alternative to this digital isolator were I can handle preferably more channels on one IC?
3. If it is a no for both 1 and 2 above, what are the best options I have for a multi-channel Opto-coupler?
4. Any other suggestions to keep the final circuit small?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, they are designed to work with 24 VDC (maximum safe voltage). With 8 per tiny SMD package, you need 3 of these ICs to solve your interface problem.
2. These are the most space efficient parts I know of. Not often interfaces have more than 8 channels.
3. You can pack them end-to-end, 3 in a row. Be sure to follow manufacture specs for board layout and decoupling capacitors. Use a linear voltage regulator so power supply is quiet. Not enough current consumed to justify a noisy switching power supply.

Comment: Will regulating with a 24 v zener work? That's the best and cheapest option I can think of as a regulator. Though, I am pretty sure that the 24 v input is well regulated, since the same is actually an output from another micro-controller board, which has a regulated power supply of its own.

Comment: Zener diodes have poor regulation. Test before connecting the IC.